# use reverse in a http response redirect in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I want to pass a variable after processing a form with reverse but after try a lot of things nothing works. Here is my code:

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def pujar_track(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        formulari = TrackForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if formulari.is_valid():                    
                track = formulari.save(commit=False)
                track.usuari = request.user
                track.save()

                url = reverse('acoplar_track', kwargs={'trac_id': track.id})
                return HttpResponseRedirect(url)

    else:
        formulari = TrackForm()

    return render(request,'principal/trackForm.html',
    {'formulari':formulari})


@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def acoplar_track(request, track_id):   
    track = get_object_or_404(Track, id=track_id)

    return render_to_response('principal/acoplarTrack.html',
        dict(track=track.nom),
        context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Url.py

```
url(r'^track/acoplar/(?P<track_id>\d+)/$',
    'principal.views.acoplar_track', name='acoplar_track'),
```

Thanks!

Comment: What response did you get?

Comment: Hopefully: "if request.method=='POSfrom django.core.urlresolvers import reverseT'" is a copy/paste error?

Comment: Yes, I've alreadty edited my post, sorry for the error

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time, finally I fixe it! I replace the http response for this and now it works: return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('acoplar_track', args=[track.id]))

Answer (score 3):

You have `track_id` in your URLConf:

```
url(r'^track/acoplar/(?P<track_id>\d+)/$', 'principal.views.acoplar_track', name='acoplar_track'),
```

In your `reverse` statement you are using `trac_id` as keyword argument. Try this:

```
url = reverse('acoplar_track', kwargs={'track_id': track.id})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
url = reverse('acoplar_track', args=(), kwargs={'track_id': track.id})
```